# ndk native package, use another .so from primary .so

Tags: android, android-ndk, package, shared-libraries

I am trying to package an .so file which is used by my primary NDK native application.

Both of my .so files are located inside apk file in the same folder. But i get error when trying to start application: "Android packaging has stopped". Code never gets executed. So i am suspecting that.so library that my primary code is using is not following some standards i guess... I built the shared .so library using ndk-build with correct processor

Comment: 1) can you execute a do-nothing function from the 1st .so? 2) can you execute a do-nothing function from the 2nd .so? 3) do you use the functions that are executed when the .so is loaded? Do they output to the log? Are they executes?

Comment: i am using no-java ndk project, so my "main" function in that first .so. I put breakpoint at first line of "main" function. The breakpoint is never hit. I do not use LoadLibrary to use second .so so it is not a dynamic function mapping. Moreover if i remove dependency in first .so to second .so then the "main" function executes normally. So i suspect my second .so has some issues. Your idea of making empty .so with one simple function and call it from first .so to test will be my next step.

Comment: ok, i tried a simple one function .so shared library. When i start emulator it still says "Unfortunately Android packaging has stopped". Even though my main .so file calls just this one function. When i comment out this call and remove linking to that .so everything works.